# Add icon in input text in bootstrap framework with Intel xdk

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, intel-xdk

I wanna add a icon from Intel xdk in input text but I cant,what should I do? I use bootstrap framework

Comment: What did you already try ?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far and tell us how it isn't working in the way that it should. Also, Bootstrap 2 ***or*** 3, which is it?

Comment: @MarcBrillault when I click on input,input properties isn't have any icon part to add icon but for button it has and now I don't know what should I do

Comment: @George bootstrap 3 in Intel xdk

Comment: @user6015571 is there a way for you to edit your message to post the HTML/CSS you've made ?

Comment: Please **provide what you have tried** in the question itself, with more detail on your actual issue, rather than simply *"but I can't*".

Comment: @MarcBrillault yes it is possible

Comment: @user6015571 please do.

Comment: @George if you work with Intel xdk it is provide for you a properties section that you can change style and theme of your input but it doesn't exist any part for add icon and on html code when I add <I>  tag it isn't work and don't add icon for me

Comment: @MarcBrillault do but isn't working

Comment: Does intel-sdk allow you to use CSS ? You should use css background image, not bootstrap-icons since this is a non-bootstrap icon you want to use.

Comment: @MarcBrillault thank u it let us use css but sth isn't work

Comment: That's why we need you to display your code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qy9W45m2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Surely you will help.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/support-glyph-and-fa-icon-inside-input